# I want to add this constraint on my schema

Tags: mysql, sql

I translating my ER diagram to a schema , However I came to this table where I only have 1 head manager or 1 record in it

```
CREATE TABLE Managers
(
SIN int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
CHECK ?????
)
```

so, does anyone knows how to push this constraint on the schema ?

Comment: Not with a CHECK constraint, I guess. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html "CREATE TABLE (MySQL)"): *The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.*

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a TRIGGER to check for that constraint.

Before you start programming that trigger, I think your data model can be further optimised.
MANAGERS should have a FK to the EMPLOYEES table. The EMPLOYEES (and CUSTOMERS) table should have a FK to the PEOPLE table.

Creating a table to store just one instance (one record) is something rare. You could have a constraint between the ORGANISATIONS and MANAGERS table, expressing that an Organisation can only have one Manager. Do that by defining a FK from ORGANISATIONS to MANAGERS. If you want to enforce the constraint that an Organisation should always have a Manager, add NOT NULL to the definition of the FK to MANAGERS.

```
CREATE TABLE ORGANISATIONS (
   Id          INTEGER     NOT NULL,
   ...
   ManagerId   INTEGER     NOT NULL,
   ...
 )
```

When you do it that way, you don't need a trigger. Triggers can be tricky. When you can avoid using them, don't use them. They are the 'dark matter' in a database. You may find stuff in your database that nobody has entered. Chances are high that is the work of some obscure trigger. Sometimes when you alter a table, the triggers defined on it may become inactive. Suddenly your database is not functioning any more as it should.... Dark matter.